# Composition of logarithmic and exponential operator is identity.

Tags: functional-analysis

> **Theorem** $:$ Let $f(z) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n,\ h(z) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n z^n$ be two convergent power series with radius of convergence of $f$ being greater than $r$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} |b_n| s^n \lt r.$ Let $g : = f \circ h$ be the formal power series. Then the power series associated to $g$ converges absolutely for $|z| \leq s$ and for such $z,$ $g(z) = f(h(z)).$

**Remark** $:$ By the above theorem it follows that if $E$ be a Banach space then for all $T \in \mathcal L (E)$ with $\|T\| \lt s$ we have $g(T) = f(h(T)).$

**Proposition** $:$ Let $T \in \mathcal L (E)$ ($E$ a Banach space) with $\| \exp (T) - I \| \lt 1.$ Then $$\log (\exp (T)) = T.$$

Here $f(z) = \log (1+z) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \frac {z^n} {n}$ and $h(z) = \exp (z) - 1 = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {z^n} {n!}$ with radius of convergence of $f$ (i.e. $1$) is strictly greater than any $0 \lt r \lt 1.$ Now I need to find out $s = \sup \left \{t\ \bigg |\ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {t^n} {n!} \lt 1 \right \}.$ Then for all $T \in \mathcal L (E)$ with $\|T\| \leq s$ we have $\log (\exp (T)) = T.$ How do I find $s$ here? Also how do I prove that $\|T\| \leq s \implies \|\exp (T) - I\| \lt 1\ $?

Would anybody please help me in this regard? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{t^n}{n!}=e^t-1$, and so, you need to solve $(e^t-1)<1$.

Comment: @Sangchui Lee yeah you are right. So $s = \ln 2.$ But now how does $\|T\| \leq \ln 2$ imply $\|\exp(T) - I\| \lt 1\ $? Thanks for your remark.

Comment: Your $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{z^n}{n}$ is $f(z)=\log(1+z)$, and so, there is no issue in your solution.

Comment: Yeah again thanks for pointing out the error @Sangchui Lee. So we need only to show that $\|T\| \leq \ln 2 \implies \|\exp(T) - I \| \lt 1.$ Am I right?

Comment: @Sangchui Lee It is easy to see that $$\|\exp (T) \| \leq \exp (\|T\|) \leq \exp (\ln (2)) = 2.$$ Am I right?

Comment: That is correct, but that is not exactly what you would want to show here. You would need to show that $$\| T \| < \log 2 \quad\implies\quad \left\|\exp(T)-I\right\|<1.$$

Comment: @Sangchui Lee yes that's what I also have said earlier.

Comment: @Sangchui Lee done it. Let me explain. $$\|\exp (T) - I\| = \left \|\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {T^n} {n!} \right \| \leq \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {\|T\|^n} {n!} = \exp (\|T\|) - 1 \leq 1.$$

Comment: @Sangchul Lee in fact the converse of the above result is also true. So actually we have $$\|T\| \lt \ln (2) \iff \|\exp(T) - I\| \lt 1.$$ So those two assumptions are equivalent in the sense that if we assume one of them then it implies the other.

Comment: I doubt that the direction $\Leftarrow$ is true. For example, if $E=\mathbb{C}$ so that $\mathcal{L}(E)$ can be identified with $\mathbb{C}$, we have $\left|e^t-1\right|<1$ if and only if $$\operatorname{Im}(t)\in\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\left(2k\pi-\frac{\pi}{2},2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \qquad\text{and}\qquad \operatorname{Re}(t)<\log(2\cos\operatorname{Im}(t)).$$ This region contains the ball $D(0,\log 2)$ of radius $\log 2$ as a strict subset.

Comment: @SangchulLee yeah you are right. Now I have a question here. It is clear from what I have shown that $$\|T\| \lt \ln (2) \implies \|\exp(T) - I\| \lt 1.$$ So the condition $\|\exp(T) - I\| \lt 1$ is weaker than $\|T\| \lt \ln (2).$ It reveals from the above discussion that whenever $\|T\| \lt \ln (2)$ we have $\log (\exp(T)) = T.$ But does the latter equality hold if I assume weaker condition?

Comment: The proposition need not hold even when $E=\mathbb{C}$. For example, note that $\left|e^{2n\pi i}-1\right|=0<1$ for any integer $n$, whereas $\log(e^{2n\pi i})=\log(1)=0$.

Comment: Oh! I see. Thanks for your kind help. So the revised version of the proposition should be the one we have discussed. Right @SangchulLee?

Comment: No problem! $\|T\|<\log 2$ will certainly provide a sufficient condition in light of our discussion. Of course, it is possible that there are some $T$ with $\|T\|\geq \log 2$ that nonetheless satisfies $\log(\exp(T))=T$. For instance, this equality holds true when $$\|\exp(sT)-I\|<1\qquad\text{for all}\quad s\in[0,1],$$ i.e., $T$ lies in a convex subset of the region $\{T\in\mathcal{L}(E):\|\exp(T)-I\|<1\}$ containing $0$. When $E=\mathbb{C}$, the set of all such $t$ is exactly $\{x+iy:\left|y\right|<\frac{\pi}{2},\ x<\log(2\cos y)\}$.